# What is the easiest and lightest way to make a client-server in Perl?

Tags: perl, client-server

It will be better if this solution is based on HTTP protocol.

Comment: What protocol? Do you want a server that listens to UDP/TCP/ HTTP? This is a very vague question. Please restate or risk closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/HTTP/Daemon.pm) in CPAN. It will give you the basics of a server. You can then over-ride methods to handle your HTTP.

Alternatively, try [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.38/lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm) although that module doesn't seem as mature as the first one.

Finally, you could take a look at [Net::Server](http://search.cpan.org/~rhandom/Net-Server-0.97/lib/Net/Server.pod), which is a more general approach.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't find HTTP::Daemon myself on CPAN... It seems close from what I was looking for, I will give it a try... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

With [IO::All](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/IO-All-0.39/lib/IO/All.pod#Client/Server_Sockets) you can make a client/server in about 2 lines of code (see link).

Answer (score -2):

HTTP Perl Client implementations are slow (one million CPU cycles just for HTTP headers mangling). Maybe try [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Curl) or better [LWP::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::Curl) which seems in the early stage but promising. On the server side use apache2 with mod_perl. If you don't require HTTP consider using [PlRPC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PlRPC/) seems very promising.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting downvoted for being incorrect. I've been active in the Perl community for many years and have yet to see anyone who is demonstrably using the stuff complain about its performance. I've also used LWP quite a bit myself and it's always been fast enough, even on old hardware.

Comment: Your requirements must be different from mine when you doesn't take care if spend one million CPU cycles just for mangle http headers (500us at 2GHz CPU). Mines are different, that is life.